# Comparator to be used with Collections.sort() for a alphanumberic list

Tags: java, sorting

So I have a list of a bunch of alphanumeric items like...

```
"123456"
"alpha"
"tango"
"beta"
...
```

I was looking to use `Collections.sort()` for the sorting of this list, but I need to sort in the order `(1234,AAAA,aaaa,BBBB,bbbb,...)` with numbers first, followed by upper then lower case words. All the elements are strings including any apparent numbers. Would `Collections.sort()` handle this case since they are all actually strings, or if not what `Comparator` would I use to accomplish this?
Or is there some other way that might be more efficient to accomplish this like using regular expressions?

Thanks.

Comment: @JBNizet because there's always someone willing to cave in ;)

Comment: I normally would JB, but at the current moment I can't code anything. I am just trying to mentally work through a bug, and figured I would check for when I can write again.

Comment: As long as by "numbers" you mean the digits 0-9, and by the "alpha" part of "alphanumeric" you don't include accented characters, the order in Unicode (and Latin 1 (and ASCII)) is the digits appear before the upper case letters, which appear before the lower case letters. However, if uppercase accented characters or, say, Hindi digits came into play, you'd need a Comparator or a Collator.

Comment: Yeah it is just using numbers 0-9 and only standard English, un-accented characters. I am going to end up using the Collator to handle not all uppercase strings appearing at the start. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1234","AAAA","aaaa","BBBB","bbbb");
Collator c = Collator.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
c.setStrength(Collator.CANONICAL_DECOMPOSITION);

Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println("without collator: " + list);
Collections.sort(list, c);
System.out.println("with collator: " + list);
```

outputs:

> without collator: [1234, AAAA, BBBB, aaaa, bbbb]
>   with collator: [1234, AAAA, aaaa, BBBB, bbbb]

Note: you may need a different collator for what you need although this one seems fine. In the worst case scenario, you can create [a `RuleBaseCollator` with your specific rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html).

Comment: Alright, thanks! I can't test this right now, but from what I can see it checks out. This should be able to work for what I'm doing.

Comment: You said in the question "... followed by upper then lower case words", but you also say that "aaaa" should come before "BBBB". I think you misstated one of those requirements.

Comment: No they have to be in alphabetical order, but if there are duplicate strings and one is uppercase, the uppercase comes first. Sorry for any confusion. AAAA->aaaa->BBBB->bbbb